# Prove that if $q\in\mathbb{Z}$ then there is $n$ such that $x^2-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ has $q$ roots at least

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Prove that if $q\in\mathbb{Z}$  there is $n$ such that $x^2-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ has at least $q$ roots.

I've seen a similar theorem: If $p$ is prime and $d|p-1$ then $x^d-1$ has $d$ roots in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, but I couldn't think of a way to apply it to solve this case.

Maybe can I use the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Do you mean exactly $q$ or at least $q$? Likely the latter.

Comment: Obviously this does not make sense for negative $a$.

Comment: @Crostul while I agree it is a bit strange to write it like this, if it means at least; which it likely has to mean, then there is no problem with negatives, it's trivially true for them.

Comment: @quid Yes, at least $q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a root of $x^2 -1$ if the element has order at most $2$ in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$.

It seems you know that for odd prime $p$ there are exactly $2$ such elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$.

Now you can, for example using Chinese Remainder Theorem, find $n$ such that $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$ has arbitrarily many elements of order at most $2$.

Recall or show that $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$ is isomorphic to  $\prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{Z}_{p^{v_i}}^{\times}$ where $n = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{v_i}$ with distinct primes $p_i$.

Comment: Can you explain how to find the n's by means of the Chinese Remainder Theorem? I thought that the module involved in the system of the CRT are supposed to be different, here all the equation need to have module $n$. And I don't understand what is the $k$ in the product below.

Comment: The application of CRT is already explained, but  perhaps that was not clear. It is used to show that  $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$ is isomorphic to  $\prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{Z}_{p^{v_i}}^{\times}$. Once this is established, it is suffices to note that you can combine an element of order $2$ in one coordinate with $1$ (or alos other elements of order two) in all other coordiantes to get different elements of order two. Or differently in the product you have  the elements $(\pm 1, \dots, \pm 1)$.

Comment: Thank you. Two last questions: By the looks of it, this generates only a pair number of roots, right? Say, if I want a $\mathbb{Z}_n$ with at least $13$ roots, I can generate it using product of the groups $\mathbb{Z}_p$ seven prime numbers, which will give me a group that has $14$ roots, right?
The second question is about uniqueness. It looks like there are multiple $N$ values, for example, the groups generated by $\mathbb{Z}^\times_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}^\times_{3}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^\times_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}^\times_{3^2}$ both have four roots but generate $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$

Comment: Yes, the number is even (except if it is $1$), in fact it is always a power of two. But that's just the way it is, and why I asked about "at least" Yes, it is by no means unique the solution. But your example seems not good. Note that $Z_2^{\times}$ is trivial.